# Is any way to stop WordPress theme upgrading notification?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a code in PHP to stop all WordPress template upgrade notifications without making any changes that harm the template I made on my [imtilak](https://imtilak.com.sa/).
and may I want the steps to put this code in my theme.
Someone to give me PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

To disable automatic plugin updates, add this filter:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
```

To disable automatic theme updates, add this filter:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating notifications serve an important purpose in WordPress, so you should think whether you really want to disable them. But if you have determined to go forward, please use the following :

**Disable WordPress Update Notification Emails**

Add the following to `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'auto_plugin_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'auto_theme_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
```

**Hide Update Notifications In Dashboard**

Add the following to `functions.php`

```
function essam_hide_update_nag() {
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}

add_action('admin_menu','essam_hide_update_nag');
```